# Multiplication of a Vector by a Scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

We were given a homework question in vectors and I'm not sure how to solve it.

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUqMA.png)

For question A, I have tried to make the vectors equal each other since they're collinear which makes them appear on the same line. So I got 2/3b = 1/2c. Now,  I'm not sure how to continue from here. In the textbook, the answer says m = 4 and n = -3, however, I'm not exactly sure how to get to here. And also it says the there are infinite values for m and n that would make the vectors null. I don't completely understand the logic behind this.

For question B, I'm not sure how to even start. I just need a lead so I could understand the principle behind this.

Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated, 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried? Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: Hi Abwatts, welcome to MSE! What have you tried? This is not a forum where people just do your HW for you. Please see
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960

Comment: I'm sorry, for question a, since the vectors are collinear,  I have tried to make them both equal to each other and I got 3/2b = 1/2c. Then, I'm not exactly sure how to continue from here...

Comment: From $\frac{2}{3}b=\frac{1}{2}c$ you can multiply by $6$ to get $4b=3c$. This gives $4b+(-3)c=0$. For (b) you can use (a). Just take $d=0$, $e=m=4$ and $f=n=-3$. Note also that you can add to $0a+4b+(-3)c=0$ the equation $4b+(-3)c=0$ as many times as you want resulting in many more relations of the form $da+eb+fc=0$.

Comment: Hi logarithm, first of all, thanks for the helpful info! For question B, did you just assume d = 0? In the textbook, it says that d = 2, e = 0, and f = -1. I don't really understand the logic behind this question at all, so it's hard for me to imagine what's going on. Do you happen to know what could been done to get to that answer? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{2}{3}\vec{b} = \frac{1}{2}\vec{c} \Longrightarrow \vec{b}=\frac{3}{4}\vec{c}$$

$$m\vec{c} + n\vec{b} = \vec{0}$$

$$m\vec{c} + \frac{3}{4}n\vec{c} = \vec{0}$$

$$\vec{c}(m+\frac{3}{4}n) = \vec{0}$$

If $\vec{c}$ is a non-zero vector, then $m + \frac{3}{4}n = 0$.

Solving for $m$ and $n$:

$$
\begin{cases}
    m+\frac{3}{4}n=0\\
\end{cases} \sim
\begin{cases}
    m=-\frac{3}{4}n\\
    n=n
\end{cases}, m, n \in \mathbb{R}
$$

Therefore there are infinitely many possible values for $m$ and $n$ in the set of real numbers, simply because we are given only 1 equation in a system involving 2 variables. If you try $n=-3$, then $m=4$. This answer is only one possible pair of values that satisfy the equation.

So with this in mind, the same could be applied for the second part of the question. Rewrite each vector in terms of $\vec{a}$ to substitute in the equation. Then you'll find that each coefficient can be written in terms of another coefficient since only 1 equation is given in the system of 3 variables. You'll find that $d$ *can* be $2$, causing $e$ to equal $0$, and $f$ to equal $-1$. But just like before, this tuple of values is an element of the entire solution set.